# Quartz.Net desktop application implementation / C#

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

My goal is to schedule a service recurring every Monday at 10:00 AM within .NET platform (specifically to send an email based on data in SQL Server database). I have found that I can use Quartz.Net to achieve this. Ideally, I want to implement Quartz.Net within a desktop application in which I could use to manage the tasks (i.e. view scheduled tasks, change the date/time of the scheduled tasks, Start/Stop the scheduled tasks, etc.).

My question is once I start the scheduled task (triggered by a button within the application), if I close the application, will it still run at the specified time or do I have to keep the application open. I have searched Google and found ways of installing Quartz.Net as a Windows service but that would not be the ideal situation as I would like the desktop application to be able to handle everything regardless of the physical computer it is running on without having to install any separate services.

Any other suggestions using different .NET methods to achieve this would be helpful also.

Comment: If your running the Quartz.net tasks within an application and you close the application, your tasks will not run because the tasks lifetime is only as long as its domain (e.g. the application).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about cross platform compatibility, I would recommend a wrapper around Windows Task scheduling services, like [this](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler) one. Your application does not have to remain open and no installation will be required.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's correct. Don't use quartz for what you want, it's far from ideal. You should build a console application that does the actual work and kick this off with the windows scheduling services.